# memory allocation of the variable having type char

Tags: c, gcc

i have the following code:

```
int main() { 
     char x='a';
     printf("integer = %ld\ncharacter  = %ld\nx = %ld\n", sizeof(int),sizeof('a'),sizeof(x);  
     return 0;  
}
```

and the output is:

> integer = 4
>   character  = 4
>   x = 1

my question is that in why the size of the ***char variable x*** is not equal to the size of the ***'a'*** .

what actually brings the difference?

thanks for the help

Comment: http://c-faq.com/malloc/sizeofchar.html

Comment: This isn't your actual code, is it. This shouldn't even compile. Give us the real code.

Answer (score 3):

Because in C single character constants (e.g., `'a'` or `'0'`) are of type `int` not `char`. This is different in C++ where they are of type `char`.

Comment: +1 especially for mentioning this as a difference from C++. I always wonder about such subtle differences, now I've got one.

Comment: @H2CO3 May be, they deliberately introduced such subtleties so as to rebut when people say "C/C++" ;)

Comment: @KingsIndian Correct!